# How to transform string "key:value" in actual map?

Tags: dictionary, go, struct

Is it possible to transform a string containing "key:value key2:value" in an actual Golang map?

Example:

```
package main

type Test struct{
  options map[string]interface{}
}

func main() {
   string := "key:value key2:key:value"
   var test Test
   /// Do something to parse string into test.Options
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Just parse the string and build the map accordingly. I don't think there is anything in the standard library that's built to parse that particular format, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Writing your own parser shouldn't be difficult, and would mostly involve use of [`strings.Split`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can definitely parse that string into a map of the type you specify!

Take a look at the "strings" package, in particular [`strings.SplitN(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#SplitN). Consider these examples and think about how you can combine them, along with iteration, to populate that map:

```
str := "key:value key2:key:value"

kvs := strings.SplitN(str, " ", -1)
// []string{
//  "key:value",
//  "key2:key:value",
// }

kv1 := strings.SplitN(kvs[1], ":", 2)
// []string{
//   "key2",
//   "key:value",
// }
```

That is, you can split the string by spaces () to get each key/value pair, then you can split by colons (`:`) to split each pair into their own parts. Finally, you just need to add each pair to the map!

Notice that when you call `strings.SplitN(...)` with -1 as the final argument it will split the input string into as many substrings as are present:

```
kv1 := strings.SplitN(kvs[1], ":", -1) // Note the -1 here
// []string{
//   "key2",
//   "key",
//   "value",
// }
```

Comment: How do you know how many times to split though? What if the string had an arbitrarily deep key/value pair? `key: key2: key3: ... keyn: value`

Comment: If we're assuming that the colon separator isn't valid in a "value" and instead represents a nested key/value pair in a new map then you simply need to use `SplitN` with n=-1 (per the first example) and create nested maps until you reach the value. I'm not going to type out the full solution without some honest work on behalf of OP =P